# django дублирование url tags

Tags: python, django

Появилась проблема большого ветвления в темплейтах. Выглядит это так:

```
{% if shop}
    {% if active_first_category %}

    <div class="left-block border-block left">
       <div class="left-block-content">
          {% for category in active_first_category.producttypessecondlayer_set.all %}
     <p><a href= "{% url 'site:supermarket_second_products_list' city.slug supermarket.slug active_first_category.slug category.slug %}"> {{ category }} </a></p>
          {% endfor %}
       </div>
    </div>
   {% else %}

   <div class="left-block border-block left">
      <div class="left-block-content">
         {% for category in categories %}
                <p><a href= "{% url 'site:supermarket_first_products_list' city.slug supermarket.slug category.slug %}"> {{ category }} </a></p>
         {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>

    {% endif %}
{% else %}
   {% if active_second_category %}
      <a href= "{% url 'site:second_products_list' city.slug active_first_category.slug active_second_category.slug %}"> {{ active_second_category }}</a>
        </div>
   {% elif active_first_category %}

      <div class="left-block border-block left">
         <div class="left-block-content">
            {% for category in active_first_category.producttypessecondlayer_set.all %}
                <p><a href= "{% url 'site:second_products_list' city.slug active_first_category.slug category.slug %}"> {{ category }} </a></p>
            {% endfor %}
         </div>
      </div>
    {% else %}
       <div class="left-block border-block left">
          <div class="left-block-content">
             {% for category in categories %}
                  <p> <a href= "{% url 'site:first_products_list' city.slug category.slug %}"> {{ category }} </a></p>
             {% endfor %}
          </div>
       </div>

    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Всё это безобразие левая панелька с навигацией. Практически для всех кейсов вид сайта одинаков: слева панель навигации, в центре список продуктов.

Соответственно обрабатываются все эти случаи одной `view` и одним шаблоном, но `url` у всех этих случаев разный и тут возникает проблема. Приходится делать огромные ветвления заменяя только `{% url %} tag` Как адаптировать я не могу понять, так же не знаю по какому запросу искать такую проблему. По ощущениям это не верный вариант решения проблемы.

Если у меня 9 урлов имеют схожую механику, делать 9 ветвлений в одном шаблоне просто невозможно. А разнести в разные, так ведь логика у них одинаковая.

Чуть уточню. Есть страница "продукты" и там есть навигация по типам, она ведёт на **продукты/тип1**, далее уже там появляются фильтры по **тип2** и ведут они на **продукты/тип1/тип2**

А есть ещё страница **магазины**, где всё тоже самое, только урлы соответственно **магазины/тип1**, **магазины/тип1/тип2**

так же будет с поиском **поиск/тип1**, **поиск/тип1/тип2**

и т.д.